# Dark insectoid race and a twist with wine or salt

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a fantasy book I read as a child,in the late 90s, early 2000, set in a medieval-like world.

My recollection is very fuzzy so some of the next elements might be incorrect.

The main plot involved a militaristic race invading the protagonist's kingdom or planet. These invaders were some form of underground living insectoid ( or humanoid with some insectoid traits ) and I remember them being described as very dark in color. Also they were capable of comunicating with the protagonists at some points but they were always emotionless in their communication.

Towards the end, there's a surprising twist that allows the protagonist to repel/placate the invaders, and I have a vague memory of this twist involving either a trade, or a donation, in salt or wine.

I remember it was in french but cannot say if it's the original language or a translation.

Can anyone identify this book based on these details?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @LogicDictates I have added information on the reading period but I have absolutely no clues as to when it was published and I don't remember anything about the cover either.

Comment: I have added some more details that came to mind.

Comment: @Valorum I take good note of the checklists you linked but unfortunately nothing much is resurfacing. I'll be sure to update if it does.

Comment: There is an insectoid race called *cho-ja* in Raymond Feist's *Riftwar* saga, specifically the *Empire" sub-series.

Comment: Highly unlikely- but perhaps an adaption of https://he-man.fandom.com/wiki/The_Good_Shall_Survive